# PowerBI and SharePoint lists: How do I count the number of rows with the PID value equal to each row's UID (the 3rd column needs the formula)

Tags: list, sharepoint, count, analytics, dashboard

I have a table below, and I need to calculate the last column as a custom measure/custom column. I'm grateful for any advice concerning the formulae. Please note this is a single table. The last column **counts the number of rows which have as PID, the respective row's UID**.

Please note, I am using SharePoint lists so addressing the ID column will be done via: **'SharePoint list name'[Id]** which is the standard syntax when calling a SharePoint list column.

```
ID    PID   Count rows
1           2
2     1     1
3     1     0
4           0
5     2     0
```

Many thanks for considering my request.

I am using Power BI Desktop 2.83.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

Create a second identical SharePoint list and use the below.

```
Additional column =
    calculate (
        COUNTROWS('SharePoint list (replica)'),
        FILTER('SharePoint list (replica)','SharePoint list (replica)'[PID]='SharePoint list'[ID])
    )
```